# Is it possible to to conditionally update a column in Hibernate 3?

Tags: java, hibernate

My scenario is that I have two different APIs updating a database table, one we will call internal and the other external, and one of them is overwriting values with stale data.

The data being updated through Hibernate is in memory in the application at the time. If the external source updates the column (statusCd) while it is still in memory at the time in the internal application, the minute it is saved in the internal application, the value will get overwritten with stale data.

Now I realize that there are many more approaches to solving this problem, **but we have identified that limiting the fixes to the Hibernate code for this object as the least risky**, as long as it is possible to do so through Hibernate.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to say through Hibernate "Yes please do Insert this value into this column when it is being created, however, please never update this value in this column unless the value is 'Cancel'?"
2. Is it possible to do a stale data check before updating, via Hibernate, in order to see if the values have been changed while still in memory in the Application?

Here are snippets of the object in question:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Object1")
@XmlRootElement
public class Object1 implements java.io.Serializable {
   private RefObject1Status statusCd;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
   @JoinColumn(name = "statusCd", nullable = false)
   public RefObject1Status getStatusCd() {
      return this.statusCd;
   }
   public void setStatusCd(RefObject1Status cd) {
      this.statusCd = cd;
   }

}
```

Thank you for your time,

Alex

Comment: i never worked with hibernate, i was using only eclipselink, so i cant tell you exact solution, but have a look at entity listeners

Answer (score 0):

You could use an @PreUpdate method as described in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html. In that method you could reset the value to its original, but you need to keep the original value for that in another property.

You could map the original property as a calculated property by using '@Formula', then it will be read only during loading:

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "statusCd")
   public RefObject1Status statusCd;


   @ManyToOne
   @Formula( value = "statusCd")
   public RefObject1Status origStatusCd;

   @PreUpdate
   public void checkStatus(){
      if(!statusCd.isCancel()) statusCd = origStatusCd;
   }
```

But this won't help if other properties were changed locally, and the external app updated the status. Hibernate never updates individual properties, it's allways a full record at once.

For this to work properly, you need to do optimistic locking with a version or timestamp column.
Your other applicaton needs to use these columns too. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5844.

If you use the version column, and your internal application tries to update the record while the external application has updated the version already, you'll get an OptimisticLockException (or StaleObjectStateException).